# Query to check if friend is already added or not

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, postgresql, select

I have a friends table that stores the userid of the users table and the user_friend_id columns.

What query should i write if i want to prevent the addition of the friend which is already added by a particular userid?

```
UserId UserFriendId
1      12
1      13
1      15
2      14
2      17
```

Comment: Do not forget to make `(UserId, UserFriendId)` the primary key.

Comment: Clodoaldo has the right answer.  To prevent entering the user / friend id twice make userid,userfriendid a primary key or a unique index.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of making it a primary key. It didn't strike me..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the value of the result (`totalCount`) is *greater than zero*, it means that two individuals are already friends.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (userID = yourID AND UserFriendID = friendID) OR
        (userID = friendID AND UserFriendID = yourID)
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` is most probably more effective. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into friends (userId, userFriendId)
select 1, 12
where not exists (
    select 1 from friends where userId = 1 and userFriendId = 12
)
```

Comment: @Erwin Although a two way friendship is perhaps the natural way of thinking the OP does not mention it and as for myself I would not make it the default.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Yes, that part is unclear. Either way, `EXISTS` is more efficient than `COUNT()` so this is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create stored procedure with 3 parameters as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUserFriends
@UserID int,
@FriendID int,
@ExcludeUserID int -- the userid you want to exclude adding his friends
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO UserFriends(UserID, FriendID)
SELECT @UserID, @FriendID
WHERE @FriendID NOT IN(SELECT FriendID FROM UserFriends WHERE UserID=@ExcludeUserID)
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Appreciate it!!